# How to check if windows accesses a file

Tags: windows, filesystems

I want to check whether or when windows (7) accesses a specific file.
There's a program that reads a certain file of which I want to replace the content right before windows reads it.
Is this possible? If so, how? On OS X/Linux there's `fs_usage` which shows the filesystem usage. Is there anything like this on Windows?

Comment: Part 1 is partially easy: process monitor can show you when and how a file is accessed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals. Now someone with an idea how to do that programatically and how to act on that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. How will you know **windows is about to read the file**? You cannot know about **future** events.

Comment: Best guesss (no internal windows knowledge here): You could intercept the file open command. Check which file is being opened, and if on a special list first do some other actions or open another file... You might also have fun getting that past any antivirus program.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, I mean halt windows when accessing that very file, replace its content and then let it continue to read that file.

Comment: @tzippy You might be able write a program to add a "hook" into the File Open API call ... but that is off-topic here. Maybe [so] can help, but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).